# What is the best way to copy a vector of cv::Mat to a vector of float?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

Suppose we have a set of `cv::Mat` objects, all of the same type `CV_32F` and the same size: these matrices have been previously inserted into a `vector<cv::Mat>`.

```
// input data
vector<cv::Mat> src;
```

I want to copy all the elements from the `src` vector into a single `vector<float>` object. In other words, I want to copy (to a destination vector) all the `float` elements contained in the matrices of the `src` vector.

```
// destination vector
vector<float> dst;
```

I am currently using the source code below.

```
vector<cv::Mat>::const_iterator it;
for (it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
{
    vector<float> temp;
    it->reshape(0,1).copyTo(temp);
    dst.insert(dst.end(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
}
```

In order to improve the speed of the copy, I tested the code below, but I only get a speedup of 5%. Why?

```
vector<cv::Mat>::const_iterator it;
for (it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
{
    Mat temp = it->reshape(0,1);   // reshape the current matrix without copying the data
    dst.insert(dst.end(), (float*)temp.datastart, (float*)temp.dataend);
}
```

How could further improve the speed of copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `vector::reserve()` to avoid repeated reallocations and copying as you insert.  And using `reshape()` shouldn't be necessary if it doesn't copy the data--`datastart` and `dataend` are necessarily unchanged.  Try this:

```
dst.reserve(src.size() * src.at(0).total()); // throws if src.empty()
for (vector<cv::Mat>::const_iterator it = src.begin(); it != src.end(); ++it)
{
    dst.insert(dst.end(), (float*)src.datastart, (float*)src.dataend);
}
```